# React Router 4 - How to append path to existing query

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, reactive-programming

I am writing an webapp that only loads when you are on a url with a query, for example:

```
http://localhost/site/?runapp=1
```

And I want to use React Router 4 in the app, but when I add a Route with a path, such as:

```
<Route path="/somepage" component={somePage} />
```

And the user clicks a:

```
<Link to="somepage">
```

to load that Route the url gets converted to:

```
http://localhost/site/somepage
```

And on refresh, the app stops working as the query is gone. How can I make React Router 4 append the paths to the needed query? I know it doesn't look pretty, but essentially I need it to route like to this url:

```
http://localhost/site/?runapp=1/somepage
```

That would make it all work, I think.

Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT: I realized that I can simply add the ?runapp=1 in every Link to get the url to be "correct", i.e:

```
<Link to="?runapp=1/somepage">
```

but it seems hacky and doesn't allow the Route to load.

Comment: ```somepage``` would have to be the sub-route of a route with a param specifying which app it was, e.g. ```<Route path="/site/?runapp=:appNumber" component={whatever}/>``` then have your ```somepage``` route in that one

Comment: Do you mean wrapping the normal routes with a wrapper route like you say there? Because I tried that but get this console error "Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored"